# Convert PDF to Excel/csv/xlsx

Tags: excel, python-3.x, export-to-csv, xlsxwriter, pdf-conversion

[My intention](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1EW.jpg) is to convert the pdf strings into excel/csv file as follows:

PDF file: (Source File)

```
#_________________________________________________________________________
appliance
n. 1. See server appliance. 2. See information appliance. 3. A device with a single or limited ......

appliance server
n. 1. An inexpensive computing .....2. See server appliance. 

application
n. A program designed ......
#________________________________________________________________________

Excel File : (Target File)
#________________________________________________________________________
appliance              , n. ,          1. See server appliance    ,
appliance server       , n. ,          1. An inexpensive co       ,
application            , n. ,          A program designed ......  ,  
_#_______________________________________________________________________
```

I have convert the pdf into text and trying to split with "," and then convert the text file into csv file. But i have stuck after converting the pdf to text file.

```
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path
import PyPDF2
from time import strftime
def check_path(prompt):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Verifies if the provided absolute path does exist.
    '''
    abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    while path.exists(abs_path) != True:
        print ("\nThe specified path does not exist.\n")
        abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    return abs_path
print ("\n")
folder = check_path("Provide absolute path for the folder: ")
list=[]
directory=folder
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            t=os.path.join(directory,filename)
            list.append(t)
m=len(list)
i=0
while i<=len(list):
    path=list[i]
    head,tail=os.path.split(path)
    var="\\"
    tail=tail.replace(".pdf",".txt")
    name=head+var+tail
    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(filename(path, "rb"))
    # Iterate pages
    for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText() + "\n"
    print (strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt ")
    f=open(name,'w')
    f.write(content.encode("UTF-8"))
    f.close
```

Comment: "i have stuck": Please provide more info about what goes wrong, what you expect etc.

Comment: I expect to parse the pdf and write down specific texts into csv file as [ https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1EW.jpg ].

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand your problem. Please provide all necessary info here in your question, not through external links

Answer (score 0):

It may be worth converting the PDF to CSV first, then manipulating the CSV to the layout you would like afterwards.

This API can be used with Python to convert one or multiple PDFs to CSV: https://pdftables.com/pdf-to-excel-api.

To convert a single PDF:

```
import pdftables_api

c = pdftables_api.Client('my-api-key')
c.xlsx('input.pdf', 'output.csv')
```

or to convert multiple PDFs:

```
import pdftables_api
import os

c = pdftables_api.Client('MY-API-KEY')

file_path = "C:\\Users\\MyName\\Documents\\PDFTablesCode\\"

for file in os.listdir(file_path):
    if file.endswith(".pdf"):
        c.xlsx(os.path.join(file_path,file), file+'.csv')
```